# Why jquery trigger doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This part should trigger click on image when #X is present in browser url... but it never happens....

```
//
var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
if (hash) {
    $("#barely_slide img[data-imgnum='"+ hash +"']").trigger("click");
} else {
    move_slide();
}
```

Actuall part that needs to be triggered:

```
//
$("#barely_slide article img").on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "focus") {return false;}
    //
        $("#barely_slide article img").removeClass("previous");
        $("#barely_slide article .focus").addClass("previous");
        var image = $(this);
$(".previous").animate({"height":300,"margin-top":0}, "fast");
    $("#barely_slide article .focus").removeClass("focus");
    image.addClass("focus");
    //
        window.location.hash = image.attr("data-imgnum");
    //
    move_slide();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor nope, no error.

Comment: What is hash in this case?

Comment: @adeneo http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLB/7/

Comment: @GurpreetSingh hash is a number #1 #2 etc.

Comment: You're not triggering the click **before** you've attached the click handler are you?

Comment: Are you not checking if the DOM is ready before attaching the events?

Comment: @Kevin jQuery(window).load(function() {}

Comment: @billyonecan Explain, noob here :P

Comment: @SandroDzneladze can you share the order in which these scripts are added

Comment: The line where you actually `.trigger('click')` - make sure that comes **after** you've attached the click handler `$('#barely_slide article img').on('click' ...`  - Otherwise you're triggering the `click` event before you've attached it, so nothing will happen

Comment: @SandroDzneladze: Your fiddle doesn't have any call to `trigger` in it. Create a [small, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the problem, post it in your question, and (optionally) also post it on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com.

Comment: @billyonecan yeaaa! it works now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to attach the `click` handler **before** you trigger it:

```
$("#barely_slide article img").on("click", function() { // attach click handler
  ...
});
```

Trigger it (this must come **after** the above):

```
$("#barely_slide img[data-imgnum='"+ hash +"']").trigger("click"); // or .click()
```

Comment: I had mine above and it was not triggering, you definitely need it below any other logic refer to what you may be doing.